# In side a R function parameter list, can I pass a parameter as a argument into another parameter?

Tags: r

For example:

Suppose I have two function one call myfunc, one call do.something. 
I want to use do.something inside myfunc.

```
myfunc <- function(parA,arglist=list(parB=parA)){
  print("parA in myfunc")
  print(parA)
  print("....")
  print("....")
  do.call("do.something", args=arglist)
}

do.something <- function(parB){
  print("parB in do.something")
  print(parB)
}
```

Now execute it.

```
a.data=matrix(1:9,ncol=3)
myfunc(parA=a.data,arglist=list(parB=parA))

[1] "parA in myfunc"
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
[1] "...."
[1] "...."
Error in do.call("do.something", args = arglist) : 
  object 'parA' not found
```

Inside myfunc, I want to pass parA to parB, but it says parA not found, how to solve it?

Comment: `function(parA, parB = parA)`?

Comment: @rawr Have you executed the code above? I see error message, the arglist in myfunc used parA, but it says parA don't exit.

Comment: When you explicitly specify `arglist`, R looks in the calling environment, and `parA` doesn't exist when you first call `myfunc`. If you leverage your default specification, you can call just `myfunc(parA = a.data)` and it works, but only because that way it's using the _default_ value for the argument, and R knows to look among the other args in the function definition.

Comment: ...the other option, of course, is simply to dispense with `arglist` entirely and just do `do.call("do.something",args = list(parB = parA))` manually.